# IIS and relative URL difference between dev and production server

Tags: iis, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, document-root

I have a web.api app that lives at `http://localhost/Reporter` on my local IIS8 server.  The index page for this site has a couple links to other pages- a correct absolute url example would be `http://localhost/Reporter/SomeRestApi`.  In the index page then, I have the following:

```
<a href="SomeRestApi">The Rest Api</a>
```

On my dev site, when I click on the link I get a valid URL.  But when I deploy this to my production IIS server (which is exactly the same version as on my local machine), when I click the link it takes me to `http://localhost/SomeRestApi` which is not right. It should be `http://localhost/Reporter/SomeRestApi`.

I have scoured the IIS settings, carefully examined my project structure on my local IIS and the production server, everything I can think of, but I can find no differences that would explain why the origin or document root seems to be incorrect on the production site.

I am deploying this with the tools in VS2012- Maybe something is tweaked there?  Where else can I look and what else can I check to try to find the problem?

Comment: Depending on your IIS settings, `<a href="~/SomeRestApi">The Rest Api</a>` should resolve the path issues.

Comment: @StevenVondruska Any idea why it would be different between the two servers though?  There are some things I use (like jQuery tabs) that require I use a simple href='SomeRestApi' to load page content into a tab area.

Comment: Venturing a guess, if it is setup as a virtual application/directory vs a subfolder?

Comment: Nope, both are applications, and everything in advanced properties shows the identical info- with the exception of the physical path on disk (which is okay).  I don't get this... is there perhaps an IIS config file that has the applications in it that I could compare?  Or something along those lines?

Comment: I'd be willing to bet it's a configuration issue somewhere. Without sitting here playing the guessing game, I'm not sure. You also may want to try [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am facing the same issue.